# Image link in jqgrid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display image link in a column in jqgrid with image name as querystring.The link should contain following path "Home\ShowImage?imageName=vlaue".

Answer (score 2):

```
function jqGridFormatter(cell, options, row) {
   return "<a href='Home\ShowImage?imageName=" + cell + ">Image</a>";
}
```

Then you need to specify this formatter in colModel options for jqGrid, see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the image through xml or json in your url parameter like this:

```
 $image = "&lt;a href='#'>&lt;img src='folders/images/arrow.jpg' border='0' valign='middle' title='Edit something'>&lt;a>";



    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?$et\n"; 
    echo "<rows>"; echo "<page>".$page."</page>"; 
    echo "<total>".$total_pages."</total>"; 
    echo "<records>".$count."</records>"; // be sure to put text data in CDATA 

        echo "<row id='". $id."'>"; 
        echo "<cell>". $image."</cell>"; 
        echo "</row>"; 
        } 
     echo "</rows>";
```

Please note that  should be written as <a>